# Detect page change in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I tried finding this question for a while but could not find this problem's answer.
My problem is that i have a `UICollectionView` and the Scroll Direction is `Horizontal` with `Paging Enabled`. My problem is that i want to keep the tack of the current page number on which the user is, so i created an `int` variable and now want to add or subtract it by 1 each time the user swipes right or left. I tried using `scrollView`'s delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

but when the user swipes right or left, it is called as many number of the times as the number of columns on a page in the `UICollectionView` plus it wont let me know that whether the user went to the next page or the previous one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting UIScrollView page change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272228/detecting-uiscrollview-page-change)

Comment: Answered **FULLY** here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057080/294884

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width;
    float currentPage = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;

    if (0.0f != fmodf(currentPage, 1.0f))
    {
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage;
    }

    NSLog(@"Page Number : %ld", (long)pageControl.currentPage);
}
```

And if you are not using any pageControl, then `ceil(currentPage)` will be your current page number.

Comment: this works perfectly as need, just couldnt understand the conditions so changed them to my own, but there is a problem, this method is called after the delegates of `UICollectionView` `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but my page number variable changes in the delegate of `ScrollView` so its not working as needed, any solution to that ?

Comment: Thats a normal behaviour, this method will only fire up when your collectionview scrolling stops..!!

Comment: yeah you are right.. i'll try to find some alternative for my situation but for the question, this is the perfect answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.  You have to cover scrollViewDidEndDragging as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057080/294884

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, at least not in iOS 15, for every case where the scroll view updates. For example, `scrollToItem` won't trigger this, even if animated is set to true. (The often recommended `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` doesn't work, either, because animations can be cancelled for other reasons).

Answer (score 46):

**Swift 3 Xcode 8.2**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let w = scrollView.bounds.size.width
        let currentPage = Int(ceil(x/w))
        // Do whatever with currentPage.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. :)

Answer (score 12):

Based on @Shankar BS 's answer I've implemented it like this in Swit. Keep in mind that CollectionViewDelegate conforms to ScrollViewDelegate:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)
    print("page = \(page)")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get the current page like below, index will be from `0` to `(total page - 1)`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    NSLog(@"Current page -> %d",page);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch.. :) is there any way that this method gets called before the `UICollectionView's` delegate `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ?

Answer (score 8):

**SWIFT 5**

For example, put this method in your ViewController with extensions UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
        let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)
        print("page = \(page)")
    }
```

Comment: Adding some explanation or comment to your answer make it more helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.2**

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let x = collectionView.contentOffset.x
    let w = collectionView.bounds.size.width
    let currentPage = Int(ceil(x/w))
    print("Current Page: \(currentPage)")
}
```

Comment: You should add some context or commentary instead of only posting code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the **currentPage** this way when the user end the dragging:

**Swift 5.6 Tested and works!**

```swift
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let itemWidth = collectionView.frame.width // Get the itemWidth. In my case every cell was the same width as the collectionView itself
    let contentOffset = targetContentOffset.pointee.x

    let targetItem = lround(Double(contentOffset/itemWidth))
    let targetIndex = targetItem % YOUR_ARRAY.count // numberOfItems which shows in the collection view
    print(targetIndex)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Xamarin.iOS:

You can override `DecelerationEnded` method of `UICollectionViewDelegate` or subscribe to `DecelerationEnded` event of `UICollectionView` (custom delegate will be used under the hood).

```cs
public override void DecelerationEnded(UIScrollView scrollView)
{
    var x = scrollView.ContentOffset.X;
    var w = scrollView.Bounds.Size.Width;
    var currentPage = Math.Ceiling(x / w);

    // use currentPage here
}
```