# Disable swipe in right direction for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, swift4, uipagecontrol

When the `offset` sits at 0, there is no need for the user to swipe left as there is nothing to see in that direction with the following code:-

```
collectionView.contentOffset.x = max(0,scrollView.contentOffset.x)
```

But what about disabling swiping right on the most `rightView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
collectionView.bounces = false
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If you would mark this as the accepted answer, that would help everyone. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understand your question, but is this what you're looking for?

```
collectionView.contentOffset.x = max(min(collectionView.contentSize.width - collectionView.bounds.width, collectionView.contentOffset.x), 0)
```

If it is, also make sure the **contentSize** is larger than the collectionView's **bounds**.

Comment: actually, I am not looking for this. My question is:
When you are at the right end, if you still try to scroll, there is a white page appearing. Im trying to block scroll on the last page so I can block that white area.

Answer (score 0):

use this implemente uiscrollviewdelegate

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {


        var bottomEdge:CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.size.width;

        if (bottomEdge == scrollView.contentSize.width)
        {
            // we are at the bottom
            self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
            self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
        } else {
            self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but the code that you shared is checking if its the right end or not, but when you scroll to right end, its presenting the left end(first one)

Comment: yes thats why i puted a comment do whatever you want i put just scroll to left

Comment: you can disable intraction of collectionview

Comment: I am trying to block scrolling to right when im at the right end. When you are at the right end, if you still try to scroll, there is a white page appearing. Im trying to block scroll on the last page so I can block that white area

Comment: have you using paging in collectionview?

Comment: yes, I have a pageController. And I have only 3 pages. So when im on the 3rd page, I don't want users to scroll right anymore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44614770/5725512 you can find the last page using this

Comment: and after that you can disable userintration

Comment: I can find the last page so easily, but I don't want to disable user interaction. Users might want to scroll back to previous one. So I only want to disable scroll to next one

Comment: Please check updated answer. if still need some improvement let eloborate